# How to use ignore pointer widget to single child scroll view item

Tags: flutter, dart

I use Ignore Pointer widget in SingleChildScrollView Widget children item but there is no pointer ignore function.

```
<!-- language: lang-dart -->
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: constraints.maxWidth,
      height: constraints.maxHeight,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            right: 0,
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 250,
              height: constraints.maxHeight,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) ...[
                      Container(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        height: 65,
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        color: Colors.white,
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            (i + 1).toString(),
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              fontSize: 22,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      const IgnorePointer(child: SizedBox(height: 4.0)),
```

> This widget doesn't do anything. Normally, when I use it on a container, it functions.

```
                    ],
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: are you trying to achive a non-scrollable SingleChildScrollView ?

Comment: I want the button located in the container under the Single Child Scroll View widget to be clickable. This is in the container Stack and the single child scrollview is also in it. I want to make sure that the section below the empty parts of the single child scroll view is clickable for the bottom part.